# Roslyn compiler version used for projects missing Microsoft.Net.Compilers

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn

Solution consists of 2 dll libraries, 1 console app and 1 web app. Only the last project, the web one, uses `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet package. Package has been updated to version 2.3.0 now, what means C# 7.1 and VB 15.3.

source: [Roslyn NuGet packages](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/NuGet-packages)

As 3 other projects do not have Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet package installed, what Roslyn compiler and C# version do they use?

I use VS.Net 2017 15.2 with .NET Framework 4.7, so I would guess it shall C#7.0, but still Microsoft.Net.Compilers in version 2.2 should be installed there, but is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` package overrides (by setting properties in your project file) the default version of Roslyn included with MSBuild / Visual Studio.

Regular class libraries that don't reference it are compiled using the Roslyn build included with your version of Visual Studio & MSBuild.

Comment: I don't believe that's true. For example, in order to test C# 7.1 code a week ago, I' added a Microsoft.Net.Compilers prerelease to the project and it compiled fine. Intellisense still showed an error, but the actual build worked (and likewise it worked from the command line).

Comment: Glad I hadn't just been confused somehow :)