# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Principal.Windows'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Solution has compiled successfully, but after I added an existing class file to the project, this error appeared:

> The specified task executable "csc.exe" could not be run. Could not
>   load file or assembly 'System.Security.Principal.Windows,
>   Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.    MvcApplicationRegister

I installed `System.Security.Principal.Windows` package By NuGet, but error still appears.

Answer (score 37):

None of the previous answers worked for me.

The problem was that I didn't have the .NET Compiler Platform SDK installed.

To solve, open Visual Studio Installer, choose "Modify", and under the "Invididual Component" tab, check the .NET Compiler Platform SDK, and confirm your changes by clicking  "Modify".

[image]

After I installed it and reopened Visual Studio, the problem is gone.

Comment: This seems to have done it for me. I don't understand why this failure has been random, though. I'm just hoping this is what really fixed it. Otherwise, problems that go away by themselves come back by themselves.

Comment: For me, the problem started after I switched machines and had to set up the environment on the new machine. I did check the old one and it had the .NET Compiler Platform SDK installed.

Comment: One detail: a colleague of mine had this unchecked and everything worked fine for him. I had to check mine and install the Compiler SDK to get stuff to work.

Comment: not sure if this did the trick, doing this and physically deleting the bin and obj folders did it for me

Comment: this followed by a rebuild and an iisreset did wonders. how did you find this was your solution? I've been working to do bindingredirects and forcing NuGet dependencies and googling...you name it. thanks for the public advice.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue after I upgraded Microsoft.Net.Compiler from 2.8.2 to 2.9.0.
After I downgraded to 2.8.2 projects compiled without any errors.

Comment: This answer made my day! Thanks!!

Comment: Because this also hit me: "downgrading" means to install an older version of the Nuget package. It's not something to be done in the VS setup app. Also consider *updating* all of your projects to the latest version because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080482/roslyn-compiler-version-used-for-projects-missing-microsoft-net-compilers

Comment: Thanks!  I did this---took it to the previous version---then rebuilt my solution to see if it worked.  It did.  So then I took it back up to 2.9.0 and tried rebuilding again.  That too worked.  Apparently something just needed to "reset".   No more issues, and I'm on the latest version again.

Comment: In my case upgrade of the compiler from 2.6.1 to 2.10.0 helped

Comment: I encountered this in a solution where one project had `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2` and another had 2.1.0.  I updated both projects via nuget to `3.0.0` (the latest stable at the time). The solution then compiled without error.

Answer (score 15):

Had this same issue and resolved it.

In a 3 project solution MVC controller (Web,Business,Data)

Caused by the Microsoft.Net.Compiler 2.9.0 being installed on the Web project but not the other projects.

To resolve:
Right click the solution.
Manage NuGet Packages.
Installed > Search for the compiler
Ensure it is the same version and it is installed on all projects in your solution

Once installed my solution built successfully
[image]

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` you can upgrade to 2.x and then remove `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` as [it's no longer needed](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider#what-shall-i-do). That solved it for me, however I couldn't even build the solution in the first place. It was still complaining about `System.Security.Principal.Windows` though, I could also solve it by referencing `System.Security` as an assembly. It's [not recommended](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider#what-does-that-mean) though.

Comment: This one worked for me, removed Microsoft.Net.Compilers before "nuget restore"

Answer (score 8):

Close down all instances of Visual Studio. Then reopen the solution and rebuild.

Comment: This one fixed for me but the reason is that I found deleting all the packages and allowing nuget to refresh fixed but when I was doing that I couldn't delete this folder because it was in use (something to do with Code Analysis) - packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\tools. So I think my case is that some process hanging to do with code analysis perhaps (even though I don't have it enabled) hangs so compilation is failing beause of this so I guess restarting Visual Studio would work as it would release process stuck on that file. (Edit: I'm using Visual Studio 2017)

Comment: On our build-server, we just re-ran the builds. Without any-changes, they built on the 2nd try. So strange, but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I uninstalled both `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` and everything now works.

Comment: `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

In my case I could go from `Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.4.0` to **`Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.10.0`**. No need to use `Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.8.2`.

Comment: Does anyone know what this package does? Why would my solution need this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not like removing packages without first understanding what I'm removing. I faced the same problem with my solution.

I discovered that 1 of the many projects was using the Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet package - let's call it Project ABC. A Unit Test project was referencing that Project ABC, but not the Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet package.

I simply referenced the Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet package from my Unit Test project, and the problem has now gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` and deleting `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here using **'System.Security.Principal.Windows'** version **4.7.0**. For some reason when I installed the nuget package it was referecing the dll from the folder: C:\Users\{your-user}\.nuget\packages\system.security.principal.windows\4.7.0\**ref**\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll **then I changed to reference the dll** from the folder C:\Users\{your-user}\.nuget\packages\system.security.principal.windows\4.7.0\**lib**\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll and everything worked just fine! So I copied the dll from the **lib** folder to my project and made a direct reference.