# C# MSBuild: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc task could not be loaded

Tags: c#, msbuild

I wrote a small C#/WPF application that builds a list of solutions with MSBuild.

These solutions can easily be built with Visual Studio 2017.
However, if I build the same solutions with MSBuild, I get the following error:

> The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded
>   from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core,
>   Version=**14.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

What is striking here is that version **14.0.0.0** is being searched for, although Visual Studio 2017 and version **15.0** are being used.

To narrow down the problem, I build a simple C# console application that only outputs a Hello World string. But I get the same error message.

I have the following constellation:
Visual Studio 2017
NuGet packages: Microsoft.Build, Microsoft.Build.Framework, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core and Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core version 15.9.20 and Microsoft.Net.Compiler version 2.10.0.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080482/roslyn-compiler-version-used-for-projects-missing-microsoft-net-compilers) that

> The Microsoft.Net.Compilers package overrides (by setting properties
>   in your project file) the default version of Roslyn included with
>   MSBuild / Visual Studio.

A downgrade of the Microsoft.Net.Compiler to version 2.8.2 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909212/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-security-principal-windows) does not change the bug.

How can I make sure that I build with the right version?